# What kind of "command line" does Azure Batch use for startup tasks on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, bash, azure

I'm having trouble getting my startup script to execute on Azure batch nodes. I'm brand new at this, so I am using the website portal rather than any CLI. I'm attempting to execute a script (from a trusted source) that I attempt to get from the web. I try to fetch this script using the box labeled "command line" on the startup task.

It doesn't seem to act like bash or sh, or really any command line I've encountered using linux. I first tried using this script:

```
wget -O - https://example.com/trustedStartup.sh | sh
```

But got the following errors where it tries to interpret my pipe as a url:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: |
>
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sh

I tried another way using curl and bash:

```
bash <(curl https://example.com/trustedStartup.sh)
```

But I got this error:

> bash: <(curl: No such file or directory

What command line interpreter is being used to give me these unexpected results? How can I download and execute my script?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww My mistake. I meant to put this on Super User. I voted to close, move to super user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It doesn't seem to act like bash or sh, or really any command line
>   I've encountered using linux.

You are right, the command line for the task, it is important to note that **the command line does not actually run under a shell**. Therefore, it cannot natively take advantage of shell features like environment variable expansion (this includes the PATH). To take advantage of such features, you must **invoke the shell** in the command line--for example, by launching `/bin/sh` on Linux:

`/bin/sh -c MyTaskApplication $MY_ENV_VAR`

> bash: <(curl: No such file or directory

According to your error message, it seems the link is not exist.

Please make sure that link is exist.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I see. So it treats the first non-space-separated string as the program to run, and the rest are inputted as arguments regardless. So to run my script I need to do: `bash -c "bash <(curl URL)"` and I see the script has access to the environmental variables. Thanks!